# Jasmine + Angular - How to test external JavaScript Script referenced in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have such code in my HTML:

```
<script src="blob.js"></script>
<script src="saveAs.js"></script>
```

Now in my angular service I have such code:

```
.success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      saveAs new Blob([ data ], type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'), 'export.xlsx'
      return
```

Despite the difficulties surrounding .success promises, how would you write a very basic test to see if blob.js and saveAs.js are available?

Comment: What do you want to test? Check that `saveAs` function was actually called?

Comment: Yes, I want to know a) its there b) it can be called. (there is a singleton inside that file with the same name)

Comment: Does this code `expect(typeof window.saveAs).toBe('function');` the thing that you need?

Comment: Looks great, I will implement it today and give feedback.

Comment: It works. You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
expect(typeof window.saveAs).toBe 'function'
```

does what I want. Thanks to just-boris.